# java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, androidx

I'm quite new about flutter and kotlin. I'm doing flutter version up(from 1.0.0 to 1.7.8+hotfix4) recently.  After I upgrade kotlin version to 1.3.10, my flutter app came into crash when I try to start it.

And the error shows like this :

```
[ +521 ms] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726): FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
[+1 ms] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726): Process: XXXXXXXXXXXX, PID: 2726 
[        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726): java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
[        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureRunningOnMainThread(FlutterJNI.java:794) 
[   +1 ms] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.invokePlatformMessageResponseCallback(FlutterJNI.java:727) 
[   +1 ms] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:140) 
[   +1 ms] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:225) 
[   +1 ms] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726):     at XXXXXXXXXXXX.MainActivity$onActivityResult$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:91) 
[        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726):     at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) 
[        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726):     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241) 
[        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726):     at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594) 
[        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726):     at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60) 
[        ] E/AndroidRuntime( 2726):     at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740) 
[  +14 ms] D/AutoManageHelper( 2726): onStart true {99992=com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbau$zza@72d039a} 
[ +983 ms] I/CrashlyticsCore( 2726): Crashlytics report upload complete: 5D72013C01D2-0001-0AA6-12B9D92A3973
```

This is the setting in `build.gradle`:

```
ext.kotlin_coroutines_version = "1.3.0"
ext.okhttp_version = "3.12.0"

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-rx2:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
```

Here is the code in `MainActivity`:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
      LOGIN_CODE ->
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          if (LoginManager.getInstance().loginService.isLoggedIn) {
            GlobalScope.launch {
              async {
                var ls = LoginManager.getInstance().loginService
                var response = ls.authRequest<AuthResponse<TokenResult>>(AUTH_PROVIDER_NAME)
                return@async response.getToken()
              }.await().let {
                methodResult?.success(it)
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          methodResult?.success("")
        }

      LOGOUT_CODE ->
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          methodResult?.success(true)
        }

      REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA -> {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
          methodResult?.success("")
        }
      }

      else -> {
        methodResult?.success(false)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should avoid using global scope, it is equivalent to creating a thread in java, you can read more [here](https://medium.com/@wackalooon/you-can-use-lifecycle-aware-coroutine-scope-e75e98b2d67f) about this.

Second thing is that you should know that you can modify UI only on the Main thread. Most probably `methodResult?.success(it)` does some UI updates, so if you want a fast fix :

```
GlobalScope.launch {
              async {
                var ls = LoginManager.getInstance().loginService
                var response = ls.authRequest<AuthResponse<TokenResult>>(AUTH_PROVIDER_NAME)
                return@async response.getToken()
              }.await().let {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                  methodResult?.success(it)
                }
              }
            }
```

When you call `GlobalScope.launch` it implies that you launch the coroutine as `Dispatchers.Default` witch means it will create a worker thread that is usually used for intensive computation, if you use it for network requests a better solution would be to launch it with dispatchers IO:

```
// instead of GlobalScope.launch 
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
  // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you !!!!It solved my problem.  Sorry, the `GlobalScope.launch{....}` is what I added, the original one is  `launch{....}`