# app crash when taking photo for the first time

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, android-activity, imagepicker

I'm new to android development.
We use flutter to develop our app. and recently we found there is a bug.
When we installed the app, and take photo for the first time the app will come in to crash.
Here is the log

```
W/libEGL  (14538): EGLNativeWindowType 0x79dd857010 disconnect failed
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](14538): surface should not be released
W/libEGL  (14538): EGLNativeWindowType 0x79d7690010 disconnect failed
E/        (14538): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(14538): notify runnable to start.
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(14538): restart watching
I/HwPhoneWindow(14538): updateLayoutParamsColor false mSpecialSet=true, mForcedNavigationBarColor=true, navigationBarColor=ff000000, mNavBarShow=true, mIsFloating=false
I/HwPhoneWindow(14538): updateLayoutParamsColor false mSpecialSet=true, mForcedNavigationBarColor=true, navigationBarColor=ff000000, mNavBarShow=true, mIsFloating=false
D/mali_winsys(14538): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/mali_winsys(14538): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
E/BpSurfaceComposerClient(14538): Failed to transact (-1)
E/BpSurfaceComposerClient(14538): Failed to transact (-1)
I/ViewRootImpl(14538): jank_removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
W/o.rakuten.plaza(14538): type=1400 audit(0.0:1351): avc: granted { create } for name="image-_20191123_1500094155171443712191881.jpg" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c203,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sdcardfs:s0:c203,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file
W/InputMethodManager(14538): startInputReason = 1
D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe(14538): stop checker.
E/        (14538): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
W/System  (14538): A resource failed to call close.
E/AndroidRuntime(14538): FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-5
E/AndroidRuntime(14538): Process: XXXX, PID: 14538
E/AndroidRuntime(14538): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/AndroidRuntime(14538):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(14538):        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:225)
E/AndroidRuntime(14538):        at XXXX.MainActivity$onActivityResult$1$invokeSuspend$$inlined$let$lambda$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:94)
E/AndroidRuntime(14538):        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/AndroidRuntime(14538):        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:241)
E/AndroidRuntime(14538):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
E/AndroidRuntime(14538):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
E/AndroidRuntime(14538):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
E/AndroidRuntime(14538):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
E/AndroidRuntime(14538):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14538):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
E/AndroidRuntime(14538):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
I/Process (14538): Sending signal. PID: 14538 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Seems it's main activity restarted.
I thought maybe the problem may be the modification I did before for kotlin version up.in here

[java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817304/java-lang-runtimeexception-methods-marked-with-uithread-must-be-executed-on-th)

Is it because of that?

Comment: Here is your answer - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29092#issuecomment-534883494

Comment: The problem is that you have already  called `methodResult?.success`

Comment: @HB Thank you.I added ```methodResult=null```  after every ```methodResult?.success```  as you suggested. And it worked, But why you said I called methodResult?.success many times? Do you mean in case of ```requestCode=LOGIN_CODE``` I set ```methodResult?.success(it)```, when I open camera, ```requestCode=REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA```, I called ```methodResult?.success("")``` again?

Answer (score 0):

`methodResult?.success()` can only be called once. Otherwise, it'll throw a "Reply already submitted" IllegalStateException. If you need to send the data multiple times, you can implement [EventChannel Streams](https://www.raywenderlich.com/20518849-an-in-depth-dive-into-streaming-data-across-platform-channels-on-flutter).